# Cannot ssh into GCP instance via Browser or CLI

Tags: google-cloud-platform

So I had a Google Cloud VM running for my final year project but was running out of credits. I created a new GCP account and tried to create a fresh new instance but I cannot ssh into it. I created new instances as well as new instances under new projects. But I cannot ssh into any of them. I've updated the ssh keys on my computer and I even changed the firewall rules to allow ssh from all ports.

But I still get `We are unable to connect to the VM on port 22. Learn more about possible causes of this issue.` when I ssh from browser and I can't ssh from CLI.

But if I go to my old account, I can ssh into the vm instance on that one just fine.

Comment: I need more logs to help out with this issue, can you try to ssh on gcloud with verbosity:   
`gcloud compute ssh --project [PROJECT_ID] --zone [ZONE] [INSTANCE_NAME] -- -vvv`

Comment: Also, be sure your user have the permission `iam.serviceAccounts.actAs` and add your user to the `Compute Engine default service account` as mentioned by [mLC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4174013/mlc) on his [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oMuqS.png)